# C++ PRJ0019 error

Tags: c++

I am getting an error while running a VC++ program. Actually I dont have any idea about the program. Its given to me by my manager just run it. Can anyone help me. The error I got is

I ran a program called slycorba and getting the below error. I have no idea what it meant.

Error   1   error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Building IDL"

Comment: Ask your manager for help. We're here for coding questions, but not for helpesk questions.

Answer (score 2):

You will also see PRJ0019 when a tool returned an error code but no error message. This can happen, for example, if you redirect the output of MIDL to NUL.

[Troubleshooting Custom Build Steps and Build Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0bktkzs(v=vs.80).aspx)

This error can also occur when you are running as a member of the Users group and Administrative access is needed. For more information, see [Running as a Member of the Users Group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173360(v=vs.80).aspx).

Or just search error PRJ0019 in google.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler bombed out when compiling the project named "Building IDL"

Without more information, that's all anyone can tell you.